# iOS 10 issue with storyboard custom view classes

Tags: ios10, xcode8, unrecognized-selector

Does anybody know why the [ZoomingPDFViewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) Apple Sample Code project no longer works? It was working prior to the iOS 10 release but now it keeps returning a *unrecognized selector* error when calling [PDFScrollView setPDFPage:].

It seems like the custom classes set in the storyboard are no longer being instantiated.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It seems that the auto conversion to Swift 3 doesn't work well with IBs.

There are two options:

a) You can set the argument label--i.e.the parameter name to be shown externally--to `_`. For example,

```
@IBAction func setPDFPage(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    // ...
}
```

b) You can remove the `IBAction` connection in the IB and re-set it. Notice instead of the previous `setPDFPage(sender:)` the connection will say `setPDFPageWithSender(sender:)` or something like that. (I didn't actually try it with the code in question, but writing from experience here.)

The same is true for segues.